# Specifically which objects will be allocated on the heap?

Tags: c++, memory-management

If a class is allocated on the heap, will everything that is allocated in that class go on the heap or only its member variables? For example:

```
class OnStackB {
    int Value;
};

class OnStackA {
    OnStackB Class;
};

class OnHeap {
    OnHeap(){
        OnStackA StackA;
    }

    OnStackB StackB;
};

int main(){
    OnHeap* Heap = new OnHeap();
}
```

I understand `Heap` will be allocated on the heap,
`Heap->StackB` will be on the heap, but will `Heap->StackB.Value` be on the stack or heap?

When `StackA` gets allocated it looks as though it will be on the stack as well as `StackA.Class` and `StackA.Class.Value`, is this true?

Comment: `Heap->StackB.value` is **contained inside** `Heap->StackB`. So if `Heap->StackB` is on the heap, then how could **possibly** `Heap->StackB.value` be on the stack? (By the way, prefer "dynamic storage duration" and "automatic storage duration" to the terms "heap" and "stack" – the C++ language doesn't have any notion of "the heap" or "the stack".)

Comment: Only the member variables. Re-"member": A member function is (with a grain of salt) like any other function with an additional hidden this parameter. Variables in these functions follow the same life time and allocation rules as those in free functions.

Comment: Yes, all of the parts of `OnHeap` will be allocated as part of `new` and thus be "on the heap". The only way to have part of a class on the stack is to have a local variable that calls `new` as part of it's construction (or some other member function) - e.g. how `std::string` allocates memory for the string itself)

Comment: Yeah.. think about it - what would be the usefulness of a heap-allocated object that became corrupt after its constructor returned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, the terms `stack` and `heap` are not defined in C++ in the way you think they are. The standard is very agnostic about allocation and talks in terms of *storage duration* rather than allocation region. When you say "allocated on the stack" you really mean *automatic storage duration*, which could involve stack allocation, register allocation, or no allocation (optimized out). When you say "allocated on the heap" you really mean *dynamic storage duration*, which could involve allocation on the *free store* (which is like an abstraction of the heap concept).

With those terms in place, we can be more exact about what is really happening here.

The storage duration of an object applies to all non-static member data of that object. So if your `Heap` object has dynamic storage duration, so will the `StackB` member and its `Class` member. It could contain a pointer to something with a different storage duration, but the lifetime of data members are directly tied to that of the object.

Inside the `OnHeap` constructor, `StackA` has automatic storage duration, along with all of its member data, so if you tried to store a pointer or reference to it, you would dive into the depths of undefined behaviour as the memory will be reclaimed when the constructor exits.